# Applying a query function to a RDD using map and lambda

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pandas dataframe with columns `id_no` and `timestamp` in epoch time so that they're integers, and I would like to identify temporally related `id_no`'s by seeing if any timestamps are occurring within a range of any others.  I need to use spark because my data set is quite large so the input format is a pandas DataFrame.

The desired output would be a tuple of `([list of time related Id_nos], number of times pattern has occured)`

```
spark_df = context.createDataFrame(DataFrame)
context.registerDataFrameAsTable(spark_df, "table1")
time_vec = DataFrame['timestamp'].unique()
timeRDD = sc.parallelize(time_vec)
def f(x):
    lo = int(x) - 1
    hi = int(x) + 1  
    temp = context.sql(str('SELECT id_no FROM table1 WHERE timestamp BETWEEN ' +str(lo) +str(' AND ') +str(hi))).collect()             
    if len(temp)>1: #making sure it detected more than just itself                
        pats = str(temp)
        Er_code = pats.replace("Row(id_no=u'", "").replace("')", "") #cleaning up the output
    return Er_code
patterns = timeRDD.foreach(f).collect()
print patterns
```

The goal is to extract id numbers that occur at a similar time. 
I have already worked out a way to do this without spark, but I need the additional parallelization because I am now working with big data. I think my code is going to find all unique time stamps in a dataframe, convert it into a spark dataframe, then convert this list of unique dates to a spark RDD, then run the query based on the different time stamps and return only the id_no's that have a matching timestamp within the range specified by lo/hi.

I have gotten this to work simply using a for loop like this:

```
time_vec = DataFrame['event_times_epoch'].unique()
timeRDD = sc.parallelize(time_vec)
pat = []
for y in time_vec:
    lo = int(y) - 1
    hi = int(y) + 1  
    temp = context.sql(str('SELECT sensor_id FROM table1 WHERE event_times_epoch BETWEEN ' +str(lo) +str(' AND ') +str(hi))).collect()             
    if len(temp)>1:                 
        pats = str(temp)
        Er_code = pats.replace("Row(sensor_id=u'", "").replace("')", "")
        pat.append(Er_code)
#patterns = timeRDD.foreach(f).collect()
print pat
```

Iteratively working through a list is very slow, so I thought parallelizing the list would speed it up but unfortunately spark sends me a long list of errors when I try to use a `foreach`.

Here is the error:

```
    patterns = timeRDD.foreach(f).collect()
  File "/home/jan/Documents/spark-1.4.0/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 721, in foreach
    self.mapPartitions(processPartition).count()  # Force evaluation
  File "/home/jan/Documents/spark-1.4.0/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 972, in count
    return self.mapPartitions(lambda i: [sum(1 for _ in i)]).sum()
  File "/home/jan/Documents/spark-1.4.0/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 963, in sum
    return self.mapPartitions(lambda x: [sum(x)]).reduce(operator.add)
  File "/home/jan/Documents/spark-1.4.0/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 771, in reduce
    vals = self.mapPartitions(func).collect()
  File "/home/jan/Documents/spark-1.4.0/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 745, in collect
    port = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
  File "/home/jan/Documents/spark-1.4.0/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2351, in _jrdd
    pickled_cmd, bvars, env, includes = _prepare_for_python_RDD(self.ctx, command, self)
  File "/home/jan/Documents/spark-1.4.0/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2271, in _prepare_for_python_RDD
    pickled_command = ser.dumps(command)
  File "/home/jan/Documents/spark-1.4.0/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 427, in dumps
    return cloudpickle.dumps(obj, 2)
  File "/home/jan/Documents/spark-1.4.0/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 622, in dumps
    cp.dump(obj)
  File "/home/jan/Documents/spark-1.4.0/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 107, in dump
    return Pickler.dump(self, obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 562, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/home/jan/Documents/spark-1.4.0/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 199, in save_function
    self.save_function_tuple(obj)
  File "/home/jan/Documents/spark-1.4.0/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 236, in save_function_tuple
    save((code, closure, base_globals))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 548, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 600, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 633, in _batch_appends
    save(x)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/home/jan/Documents/spark-1.4.0/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 199, in save_function
    self.save_function_tuple(obj)
  File "/home/jan/Documents/spark-1.4.0/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 236, in save_function_tuple
    save((code, closure, base_globals))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 548, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 600, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 633, in _batch_appends
    save(x)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/home/jan/Documents/spark-1.4.0/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 199, in save_function
    self.save_function_tuple(obj)
  File "/home/jan/Documents/spark-1.4.0/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 236, in save_function_tuple
    save((code, closure, base_globals))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 548, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 600, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 633, in _batch_appends
    save(x)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/home/jan/Documents/spark-1.4.0/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 199, in save_function
    self.save_function_tuple(obj)
  File "/home/jan/Documents/spark-1.4.0/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 236, in save_function_tuple
    save((code, closure, base_globals))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 548, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 600, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 636, in _batch_appends
    save(tmp[0])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/home/jan/Documents/spark-1.4.0/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 199, in save_function
    self.save_function_tuple(obj)
  File "/home/jan/Documents/spark-1.4.0/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 236, in save_function_tuple
    save((code, closure, base_globals))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 548, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 600, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 636, in _batch_appends
    save(tmp[0])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/home/jan/Documents/spark-1.4.0/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 199, in save_function
    self.save_function_tuple(obj)
  File "/home/jan/Documents/spark-1.4.0/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 236, in save_function_tuple
    save((code, closure, base_globals))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 548, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 600, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 636, in _batch_appends
    save(tmp[0])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/home/jan/Documents/spark-1.4.0/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 518, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 306, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 726, in __getattr__
    raise Py4JError('Trying to call a package.')
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: Trying to call a package.
```

I think that the `foreach` command should do what I want, but obviously it doesn't. I've tried other permutations of, such as using a `.map(lambda x: f(x))` function but with no success.  Every time it raises the same error calling a package.

Comment: Maybe this will be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31164595/1560062

Comment: I don't think that's quite what I'm doing  ill edit the post to make sure I make my question clear